# After Effects Audio Ahead of Video in Preview and Render

Tags: after-effects, premiere, video-editor, audio, adobe

I was working on my first large-ish upload for youtube, put it together quickly and didn't notice until it was complete that almost the entire video was riddled with audio desync issues. You can find that [HERE](https://youtu.be/yxOjNRgC2dc)

I took another look at it today, and discovered a large factor may have been the video frame rate (Windows shows the video as 60FPS but when imported into AE it shows a frame rate of 59.993) [HERE](https://streamable.com/goeg79)  is another example of the slight premature audio with 59.993 composition even after wiping all cache and stored data, starting a new composition, etc.

All of the footage except 1 clip was recorded in the span of 2 days, but yet some clips do not (or at least not visibly) suffer from the desync issue. The Waveform is in line with the out of sync audio.

Any idea what could be the cause? Or what I can do to get the issue resolved?

*PC Hardware:*
i9 9900k /
32 GB RAM /
1080ti GPU

*RAW Video According to Windows:*
2560 x 1440 /
195kbps bit rate /
48.000khz

*Imported RAW Video According to AE:*
2560 x 1440 /
h.264 /
48.000khz / 32 Bit U

*Composition Settings:*
1920 x 1080 /
Originally 60FPS, Streamable example was corrected to 59.993

Thank you,

Nexu

Answer (score 1):

I think you’ve probably identified the cause. I’ve found when using mobile phone footage (And video conference captures) both premiere and after effects can incorrectly identify frame rates. If all the footage is around 59.93-60fps, I would try transcoding it all to 60fps first using a codec suitable for editing (like ProRes), making sure it’s all in sync after transcode, then re inserting it into your project (save a new copy of your project first though).